# url not found sending an encoded parameter on the url

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I've set this url on routes

```
$route['usuario/login_no_pass_no_data/(:any)']['GET'] = 'Public/Login/no_pass_no_data/$1';
```

but when I try to make a request with a url like this

http://mydomain/usuario/login_no_pass_no_data/1JZsJnvUHe%2BGivuFoQEBuV6fz1SXoiYxxw39bjZKoFhxZG98XIm8CDKMky1cZOSoWu4nJqYia0gEmYXbO%2F2elHb%2F3tP2hppPMowf4q2eaOs%3D

I get this error

`The requested URL /usuario/login_no_pass_no_data/0SnjpV8gDCygjV+U0kwk861UmVEa9clv47SPv0oICbw4s5aQTvhXLpUc0nSWe7eExP5oQFHat1/gZXXu5TDR59rWMdaUotZKV2EOdeNh6xQ= was not found on this server.`

this is the function

```
public function no_pass_no_data($encoded_email){
        //$encoded_email='0SnjpV8gDCygjV%2BU0kwk861UmVEa9clv47SPv0oICbw4s5aQTvhXLpUc0nSWe7eExP5oQFHat1%2FgZXXu5TDR59rWMdaUotZKV2EOdeNh6xQ%3D';
        $encoder = $this->di->find('ssl_cipher');
        $storage = $this->di->find('storage');
        $salt = $storage->executeSQL("select text from translations where entity='Salt'", \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)[0]['text'];
        $decoded_email =  $encoder->decode(urldecode($encoded_email), $salt);
        $client = $storage->findOneBy('Client',array('email'=>$decoded_email));
        $this->login_user($client->getId());
        redirect('usuario/datos','location');
    }
```

If I uncomment `$encoded_email`, everything works so it's a problem with the url not being recognized, but I don't know what the problem

Comment: `(:any)` is supposed to match anything but `/`. Your value does not contain `/` directly, but the URL-encoded form `%2F` - my guess would be that this gets automatically decoded somehow before it even arrives at your router. Are you running this on an Apache? Then go check what [`AllowEncodedSlashes`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes) is set to, that’d be my first suspect here.

Comment: Solved ,thak you